# Swift - Parse em HTML

Tags: ios, swift

Atualmente tenho um projeto para IOS 9 onde tenho um componente UIWebView, estou recuperando uma página da internet e apresentando dentro deste componente.

Mas meu objetivo é pegar somente o primeiro formulário que é apresentado dentro do HTML, ou seja, quero retornar somente o HTML do primeiro form e o apresentar no UIWebView formatado como página web. Alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: em português é muito dificil encontrar bons materiais, mas neste link aqui, você encontrara o que procura e de forma bem didática, Eu acho: http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios  Espero que lhe ajude.

Comment: Aqui também: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28261570/parsing-html-in-swift-other-than-using-regex

Comment: Preciso de algo que seja puramente em Swift, o material pode ser em português, inglês ou espanhol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá.

Você pode usar o framework [hpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple/) para isto. O framework é construído em Objective-C, mas você consegue usar ele em Swift. Fiz um exemplo simples, que carrega uma página HTML com dois forms (distribuída junto com a app), faz o parse do HTML e mostra apenas o primeiro form.

Esta é a página HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test page with 2 forms</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Form 1</h1>
        <form id="form1" action="your_action_here">
            <input type="text" value="You name here">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

        <h1>Form 2</h1>
        <form id="form2">
            <input type="text" value="You name here">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Fiz um ViewController simples, que encontra e carrega o primeiro form HTML no método viewDidLoad.

```
import UIKit
import hpple

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let htmlFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("index", ofType: "html", inDirectory: "www") {
            let htmlData = NSData(contentsOfFile: htmlFile)
            let htmlDocument = TFHpple(HTMLData: htmlData)
            if let htmlElements = htmlDocument.searchWithXPathQuery("//form[@id='form1']") as? [TFHppleElement] {
                if let firstForm = htmlElements.first?.raw {
                    webView.loadHTMLString(firstForm, baseURL: nil)
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("File not found")
        }
    }
}
```

Você pode ver o código-fonte completo neste [repositório no GitHub](https://github.com/lucasdamiani/parsing-html-with-hpple). Eu usei o [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org) para adicionar a dependência do hpple. Se você quiser mais informações sobre o CocoaPods, pode ver este [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift).

Comment: Se o form tiver um action preenchido, ao clicar no botão de submit o formulário será enviado e terei o retorno dado pela página web? Isso estou me referindo a um link de internet.

Comment: Não fiz o teste, mas acredito que sim. Contudo, você deve considerar algumas coisas:
1. O form extraído não irá aparecer formatado. Você terá que criar uma página e adicionar o CSS que veio da página origem para exibir o HTML corretamente.
2. Caso a página tenha algum comportamento dinâmico, você terá que carregar o JavaScript também.
Sugiro que você faça isso de uma outra forma, simulado um post para a action que está descrita no form. Isto é algo mais robusto do que mostra um pedaço da página. Sugiro que você fale com o dono da página para ver se você realmente pode usar esta técnica.

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigado.